# Correct Xpath -

Tags: xpath

I have a xml like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oslc_cm:Collection xmlns:oslc_cm="http://open-services.net/xmlns/cm/1.0/" 
                    oslc_cm:totalCount="7" 
                    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
                    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                    xmlns:rtc_cm="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/rtc/cm/1.0/">
  <rtc_cm:Action rdf:resource="https://rtc.gsissc.myatos.net:9443/ccm/oslc/workflows/_ezLt4PJ7EeGRg6GNKwqw9g/actions/com.ibm.team.workitem.defectWorkflow/com.ibm.team.workitem.defectWorkflow.action.resolve">
    <dc:identifier>com.ibm.team.workitem.defectWorkflow.action.resolve</dc:identifier>
    <rtc_cm:resultState rdf:resource="https://rtc.gsissc.myatos.net:9443/ccm/oslc/workflows/_ezLt4PJ7EeGRg6GNKwqw9g/states/com.ibm.team.workitem.defectWorkflow/3"/>
    <dc:title>Resolve</dc:title>
    <rtc_cm:iconUrl>https://rtc.gsissc.myatos.net:9443/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.model.IImageContentService/processattachment/_ezLt4PJ7EeGRg6GNKwqw9g/workflow/resolve.gif</rtc_cm:iconUrl>
  </rtc_cm:Action>
```

From it I have to fetch `rtc_cm:resultState rdf:resource`.

What would be the correct XPath for it. I am using `XPathExpression xPathExpressionDescription = xpath.compile("../rtc_cm:resultState/@rdf:resource");` which is giving me null pointer.

Please guide me .

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  ../rtc_cm:resultState/@rdf:resource
> ```

That's assuming the context node – the node to which your XPath expression is relative – is a sibling of `rtc_cm:resultState`.

You might be better with an absolute path, based on the document root. Something like:

```
/oslc_cm:Collection/rtc_cm:Action/rtc_cm:resultState/@rdf:resource
```

(and, of course, assuming you are passing an implementation of `IXmlNamespaceResolver` set up with all the applicable namespaces).

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path would be:

```
/oslc_cm:Collection/rtc_cm:Action/rtc_cm:resultState/@rdf:resource
```

If you know there is only one instance of resultState or if you want to query for all instances:

```
//rtc_cm:resultState/@rdf:resource
```

Please make sure that your namespace manager has definitions for the namespaces you use in your XPath expression.